# Call a method from superclass of superclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, superclass

I have a example. I have two classes. `A` is the superclass of `B`.

```
class A(object):
   def p(self):
      print "a"


class B(A):
   def p(self):
      print "b"
      super(A, self).p()
```

Now i have a new class `C`. The class `C` is the child class of `B` and should overwrite the method `p` again, like that:

```
class C(B):
   def p(self):
      print "c"
      # here call the method p of the 'supersuper'class A
      # without calling the method p of the superclass B
   ...
```

How can i overwrite the method `p()` of the *superclass* `B` in the class`C` and call the method `p()` of the *supersuperclass* `A` **without to call the method `p` of the superclass `B`**? Has someone a idea?

*P/S: The method name must be identical.*

Comment: Well, it's Python, we're all consenting adults here, so it'll allow you do something like `A.p(self)` or walk manually through `self.__mro__`, but your requirement breaks some basic inheritance rules and it won't be supported nicely.

Comment: Yes, i know, that it isn't nice. But i need to inherit a class to change his method without editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `A.p(self)` directly, this is not what `super()` was designed to support. Note that you have to pass in `self` manually as `A.p()` is an *unbound* method.

However, you want to reconsider your class design. Perhaps you want to introduce helper methods; one of these could then be called from `A.p()` and `C.p()` but not `B.p()`? That way `B.p()` wouldn't have to use `super().p()` *at all*, and simply just reuse these helper methods.

Comment: We came across a similar issue at work the other day -- caused by bad class design, to be sure -- but we were thinking of doing something like this just to get through the sprint. What would potentially break if in `C` you did something like `super(B, self).p()`, as long as you're not using multiple inheritance? (Only asking because I know you'll know.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: nothing would break because `A` is then always the next class in the hierarchy. Provided you never mix in `A` or `B` down the line via multiple inheritance somewhere. However, explicit is definitely better than implicit here. Will you remember, in a year's time, that `super(B, self)` starts searching at `A` now?

Comment: I have built my program based on your answer. And it works now. Thanks Martijn